# Should I show Hotel reservation when entering Schengen zone?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, bookings, prague

I already have a single entry visa from Czech republic.

While applying, my plan was to travel to Prague stay there 3 nights including my date of arrival & 3rd day depart to Germany, spend there 2 days & back to Prague and stay there 1 day, & depart to my resident country.

Now my current plan is to enter Prague & later morning take a flight to Brussels, go sightseeing & take night trains, travelling through countries like the Netherlands, Germany & Austria & back to Prague on the 6th day where I have a hotel booking, then next day return back to my resident country.

I will be reaching Prague on 2nd November midnight & I have booked another flight from Prague to Brussels on the very same day early morning flight. I already have return ticket booked to my resident country, and all the bus/train night tickets & other tickets throughout countries which I will travel & 1 hotel bookings which I have taken in Germany.

So when entering Prague, should I show them the hotel reservation in Prague? Or should I show them flight booking to Brussels which is same day travelling? Will they make any issues in airport? The bookings I submitted with my visa processing, I cancelled after the visa was approved.

- I could make some free cancellation bookings in Prague from November 2nd to another few days, finish the immigration process and enter the country then later in morning I can get back to terminal 2 & proceed to Brussels as normal domestic travel.
- Or I could show the Brussels ticket & convince them that I will travel to Brussels and will be back to Prague on November 4th and will be staying in Prague for 5 days, by showing them some free cancellation hotels bookings from Nov 4 to Nov 9.

Which is better?

Comment: Can you clarify: what were the travel plans you presented when you made your visa request (number of days/nights spent in each country), and what are your actual current plans? Are you indeed returning to the Czech Republic? When? For how long? As it stands, it looks like you "visa-shopped" by requesting a visa from the Czech Republic when you actually wanted to go to Brussels (and never return), which can get you into quite a bit of trouble. Also, even beyond that, the piece of evidence they will most likely want to see is your ticket out of the Schengen Area.

Comment: Trying to lie to an immigration officer is a very bad idea. Your plans have changed substantially. How many days/nights are you planning to spend on each country? Unless you are staying in the Czech Republic the most, or the principal reason of your trip (e.g. a business meeting) is on the Czech Republic, your visa is no longer valid for your travel. They may not even ask anything, but if they do, they will quickly find out. Make sure your travel plans still include the longest number of days in the Czech Republic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We say don’t try to trick them, show them the true documents if asked for.

All these *Fake bookings* might get you a *Real booking* : **A flight straight back home.**

If you get caught up in these *free cancellation* (fake as i call them for this use case) bookings you might appear like you were visa shopping and Czech Republic wasn't your primary destination. To avoid any such impressions, tell them the truth about the change in your plans.

**Only when asked**, there is no need to volunteer a story.